# Third person plural pronoun for group with both masculine and feminine

Tags: pronoms-personnels

> **Marie et Jean** vont à la cantine.

Now, according to the rule we should replace the noun with *ils* or *elles* according to their gender.

But here there is a masculine as well as a feminine, so what should I place here?

Answer (score 8):

The usual rule in French is called "Le masculin l'emporte". It means that when you have both genders in a phrase, the masculin takes precedence.

It also works for adjectives and verbs:

```
Marie et Jean sont allés à la cantine.

Le camion et la voiture sont verts.
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use *Ils* as explained by Luke and Gilles. **But**, we see more and more sentences like:

> Nos collègues sont invité.e.s à participer sous réserve de l'accord de
>   leur supérieur.e hiérarchique.

Where *invité.e.s* is a way to express the importance you give to the female people: *collègues* can represent men and women but the author deliberately uses a syntax that is supposed to represent both using the dots.

In the same way *leur supérieur.e hiérarchique* is a way to say that your superior can be a man or a woman. NB: in this case, a more classical way could have been:

> de leur supérieur (ou supérieure) hiérarchique.

PS: I know this is not an answer and should have been published as a remark but the number of characters is too small and the rendering too poor. Don't vote for this answer. Thanks on behalf of women ;)

Comment: If you ask me this is feminism vs grammar. The rule is clear and is in no way "against" women, only to simplify writing...

Answer (score 3):

It becomes *ils*.

According to Wikipedia's article on [French personal pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#Overview):

> In French, a group containing at least one male or one masculine noun is considered masculine, and takes the pronoun *ils*. Only exclusively female or feminine groups take *elles*.

---

Aside: When I was learning French, I wanted to test this rule and pestered the teacher with questions like "What if there are 99 women and one man?" Since then I've found that [this is a common question](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/11692/Ils-and-elles). In real life such extreme cases probably depend on how formal you're being. But the officially correct answer in all such cases is *ils*.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt this the other day in my GCSE lesson,

Say you have a group of 100 GIRLS then they are referred to as 'ELLES'. All it takes is for 1 BOY to be added into the group and now the group is referred to as 'ILS'.

If you are comparing a girl to a boy, for example, Sophie is more tall then Billy, the french for taller would be the female way. so it will be: Sophie est plus grande que Billy. 
However, if you are comparing Billy to Sophie then the 'GRANDE' will change to 'GRAND':
Billy est plus grand que Sophie.